# jquery cycle plugin with thumbnails scrollable

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

I am trying to integrate the cycle jQuery plugin in my application but i need to make the thumbnails scroll from the left and from the right.  Is there a way to configure the scroll direction of the thumbnails?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jsFiddle scrolling left
http://jsfiddle.net/fUNnJ/

here is the HTML

```
<div class="slideshow">
    <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach1.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach2.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach3.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach4.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach5.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
</div>
```

the JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollLeft'
    });
});
```

or you could use this to scroll Right.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollRight'
    });
});
```

Go here for all transitions http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/begin.html